# A very, very, very big div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

For a project of mine (see [BigPictu.re](http://bigpictu.re/demo) or [bigpicture.js GitHub project](http://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/)), I have to deal with potentially a very, very, very big `<div>` container.

I knew there was a risk of poor performance with the simple approach I use, but I did not expect it to be mostly present with ... Chrome only!

If you test [this small page](http://gget.it/caveot4g/big-div-test.html) (see code below), panning (click + drag) will be:

- Normal / smooth on Firefox
- Normal / smooth even on Internet Explorer
- Very slow (nearly crashing) on Chrome!

Of course, I could add some code (in my project) to do that when you're zoomed in a lot, text with potentially very very big font-size would be hidden. But still, **why does Firefox and Internet Explorer handle it correctly and not Chrome?**

**Is there a way in JavaScript, HTML, or CSS to tell the browser *not to try* to render the whole page (which is 10000 pixels wide here) for every action?** (only render the current viewport!)

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                overflow: hidden;
                min-height: 100%; }

            #container {
                position: absolute;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%; }

            .text {
                font-family: "Arial";
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="text" style="font-size: 600px; left:100px; top:100px">Small text</div>
            <div class="text" style="font-size: 600000px; left:10000px; top:10000px">Very big text</div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var container = document.getElementById('container'), dragging = false, previousmouse;
            container.x = 0; container.y = 0;

            window.onmousedown = function(e) { dragging = true; previousmouse = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY}; }

            window.onmouseup = function() { dragging = false; }

            window.ondragstart = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }

            window.onmousemove = function(e) {
                if (dragging) {
                    container.x += e.pageX - previousmouse.x; container.y += e.pageY - previousmouse.y;
                    container.style.left = container.x + 'px'; container.style.top = container.y + 'px';
                    previousmouse = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [OT] 600K font size. Must be an accessibility feature for people with *very* bad eye sight? ;-)

Comment: @geert3 I'm sure it's for a lunar orbiting web browser

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m.

Comment: Your demo is smooth in Chrome 41.0.2236.0 dev-m

Comment: It's also smooth on Chrome 35.0.1916.153

Comment: I'm in canary (41.0.2241.0 canary) and I'm still getting the lag. You guys should try it on a laptop instead of a gaming rig, you'll see it

Comment: @Markasoftware do you still have the lag with http://gget.it/e0ubdh67/big-div-test_fixed.html (according to solution given by geert3) ?

Comment: Oddly, if I try and record the paint and memory usage in the example link using the dev tools, it breaks the dragging altogether without the use of `position:fixed`. Chrome 40.0.2214.28 beta-m (64-bit). Sounds like a layout bug?

Comment: Smooth in Chromium 27.0.1421.0.

Comment: I am on Chrome 39.0.2171.71, the demo is terribly lagging, but the geert3 solution works fine.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, IE is actually faster than Chrome for rendering most pages. Its javascript engine is a little slower though.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Changing to `position: fixed` seems to speed things up.

Comment: It is not a direct answer to his question, but it is a potential solution to his initial problem (slow response in Chrome). Thinking outside the box should be encouraged, IMHO.

Comment: I can only guess. `fixed` is obviously less complex to lay out and perhaps they can do more optimizations. But I haven't looked at the rendering engine source code if you mean that ;-)

Comment: This answer, and the one provided by ViliusL, both have the same "leave a comment" comment, by different people. How cool is that?

Comment: @Joe these are from a set of standard answers provided by StackOverflow for use by moderators. Some need to moderate more moderately though.

Comment: @geert3 Not by moderators - by *everyone* who has enough reputation to review the Very Low Quality queue, which very short answers such as this one are automatically added to. You are correct, though, that there's nothing wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 42):

Use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) instead of `top/left`:

```
container.style.transform = 'translate(' + container.x + 'px, ' + container.y + 'px)';
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1LL1vb4/).

Comment: A **very strange** thing : in your jsFiddle, it is fast with Chrome indeed. I did *exactly* the modification that you propose in my original code here : http://gget.it/1owxq8kr/big-div-test_transform.html,  and this last link is slow on Chrome :(   How is this possible? It looks the same as your jsFiddle!
[Note : miraculously, geert3's answers seems to work, I don't know why but it works: http://gget.it/e0ubdh67/big-div-test_fixed.html]

Comment: @Basj Maybe it's version dependent, my Chrome (39.0.2171.71 m) pans the page linked in your comment as smooth and fast as FF. Anyway, setting position to `fixed` takes the element out of text-flow and saves a lot of re-rendering. In the documentation of `transform` MDN says: "... a stacking context will be created. In that case the object will act as a containing block for position: fixed elements that it contains."

Comment: Ok @Teemu, this MDN citation would explain why the solution with `position: fixed` (http://gget.it/e0ubdh67/big-div-test_fixed.html ) works as well ?

Comment: Strange, I have Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m as well... and http://gget.it/1owxq8kr/big-div-test_transform.html pans slow, as slow as my original version (in the question itself). Oohhh possibly it depends on hardware acceleration : I probably have no hardware acceleration, because I have a laptop with a poor graphic chip...

Comment: @Basj A hardware issue wouldn't explain why my fiddle worked for you, the codes seems to be identical. As a sidenote, when having more content in a draggable `div` (images and more text for example), `transform` is much faster in FF and Chrome, using traditional `top/left` positioning is slow even with `fixed` position.

Comment: Try `translate3d` instead of `translate` to enable hardware acceleration.

Comment: @Basj add a wrapper `<div style="position:relative;min-height: 900px;">Your's divs</div>`[jsFiddle so does](http://fiddle.jshell.net/p1LL1vb4/show/)

Comment: @AlfonsoRubalcava Oh ok... This explains why the jsfiddle is smooth and the direct link not smooth (Chrome) : http://gget.it/1owxq8kr/big-div-test_transform.html ! Thanks! So the improvement in performance comes from the `position:relative` propbably, which is similar to geert3's answer

Answer (score 23):

1. Answer to first quest "why". One of problems are **font size**. you have font size 600000px, most browser will see it as too high and render smaller, while chrome tries to render original size. Looks like chrome can not repaint such big letters with your requested styles very fast.

But combining Teemu and geert3 answers - using transform and position:fixed, makes chrome works much more faster even with big fonts.

2. Answer to 2nd question: "Is there a way ... not to try to render the whole page" - you can try to apply mouse action for elements in container, not for whole container.

Maximum font sizes: http://jsfiddle.net/74w7yL0a/

```
firefox 34 - 2 000 px
chrome 39 - 1 000 000 px
safari 8 - 1 000 000 px
ie 8-11 - 1 431 700 px
```

Comment: It does, actually. The OP asks two questions, the former of which is answered: "why does FF, IE handle it correctly and not Chrome?"

Comment: Interesting. Do you have some elements in mind that show that Firefox stops at 10k and that Chrome tries to render original size? (It would be interesting for future reference). Thanks in advance @ViliusL !

Comment: @Basj added maximum font sizes for each browsers (tested today), and it is 2k for firefox.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ViliusL! Indeed, FF limits the `font-size` and this could be the reason for no-slowness on FF. But then it should have been very slow on IE too, but it's not... Strange!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Teemu's answer of using translate:

```
container.style.transform = 'translate(' + container.x + 'px, ' + container.y + 'px)';
```

Which you should also use other vendor prefixes, You can simply fix this by using this on the body:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

and this on html:

```
height: 100%;
```

this will, however, disable scrolling. So what I'd do is, add a `mousedown` event to the body and apply those styles using a css class whenever `mousedown` is triggered, and removing that class on `mouseup`.

Comment: I tried to add what you mentioned here : http://gget.it/0ufheqmt/big-div-test_prisonersolution.html , is it what you meant ? 
Here it's still slow on dragging with Chrome. The same for you?
(PS: I didn't understand: you suggest to do these CSS modifications *instead* of using `style.transform` or *with* using `transform` ?). Thanks by the way for your answer @Prisoner !

Answer (score 2):

@Teemus' answer almost does it all.

Use `transform` *with `translate3d`* instead of `top/left`.

`translate3d` enables hardware acceleration.

```
container.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + container.x + 'px, ' + container.y + 'px, 0)';
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koenpunt/k7zv73k0/2/).

Answer (score 1):

I analyzed this and I found that the original problem related to the Chrome display architecture, and its use of background threads to render the page.

If you want to have fast rendering, go into chrome:flags, scroll to the setting Impl-side painting, and set "Disabled", then restart the browser - the mousemove will be smooth.

What I found is that if you enable the FPS counter, the reported FPS in this scenario is still very high, even though the actual onscreen performance is very low.  My tentative explanation (not being a Chrome display architecture expert) is that if the UI thread and display are on separate threads, then there can be contention in the rendering of the div - in the case where the UI thread and rendering thread is on the same thread, the UI thread cannot send messages faster than the UI thread can render.

I would suggest that this should be filed as a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table` and `table-layout:fixed` on the div, or a table wrapping the div. In HTML:

> The HTML table model has been designed so that, with author assistance, user agents may render tables incrementally (i.e., as table rows arrive) rather than having to wait for all the data before beginning to render.
>
> In order for a user agent to format a table in one pass, authors must tell the user agent:
>
> The number of columns in the table. Please consult the section on calculating the number of columns in a table for details on how to supply this information.
>      The widths of these columns. Please consult the section on calculating the width of columns for details on how to supply this information.
>
> More precisely, a user agent may render a table in a single pass when the column widths are specified using a combination of COLGROUP and COL elements. If any of the columns are specified in relative or percentage terms (see the section on calculating the width of columns), authors must also specify the width of the table itself.
>
> For incremental display, the browser needs the number of columns and their widths. The default width of the table is the current window size (width="100%"). This can be altered by setting the width attribute of the TABLE element. By default, all columns have the same width, but you can specify column widths with one or more COL elements before the table data starts.
>
> The remaining issue is the number of columns. Some people have suggested waiting until the first row of the table has been received, but this could take a long time if the cells have a lot of content. On the whole it makes more sense, when incremental display is desired, to get authors to explicitly specify the number of columns in the TABLE element.
>
> Authors still need a way of telling user agents whether to use incremental display or to size the table automatically to fit the cell contents. In the two pass auto-sizing mode, the number of columns is determined by the first pass. In the incremental mode, the number of columns must be stated up front (with COL or COLGROUP elements).

and CSS:

> 17.5.2.1 Fixed table layout
>
> With this (fast) algorithm, the horizontal layout of the table does not depend on the contents of the cells; it only depends on the table's width, the width of the columns, and borders or cell spacing.
>
> The table's width may be specified explicitly with the 'width' property. A value of 'auto' (for both 'display: table' and 'display: inline-table') means use the automatic table layout algorithm. However, if the table is a block-level table ('display: table') in normal flow, a UA may (but does not have to) use the algorithm of 10.3.3 to compute a width and apply fixed table layout even if the specified width is 'auto'.

**References**

- [HTML 4: 11.2, Elements for constructing tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2)
- [HTML 4: Appendix B, Section 5.1.2: Incremental Display](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/appendix/notes.html#h-B.5.1.2)
- [HTML 5: Algorithm for Processing Rows](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#algorithm-for-processing-rows)
- [CSS2: 17.5.2 Table width algorithms, the 'table-layout' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout)
- [Draft U.S. Web Design Standards Documentation | Tables](https://standards.usa.gov/tables/)